# Looking for streaming server options

Tags: gratis, linux, video, streaming

A client of mine has a digital TV broadcast center that distributes TV channels to multiple rooms. This broadcast center can also distribute up to 10 UDP multicast streams.

Right now I've set up a laptop with VLC to stream a given playlist of MP4 files to the broadcast center over ethernet. It works OK, but to add or remove a video from the playlist we have to stop broadcasting and go through the setup process again. This involves setting IP address and port number and isn't for non-technical users.

What I really want is a nice UI that people without technical knowledge can use to add and remove video's to the playlist. Do you guys know any software that does this? Preferably free and Linux-based with a web interface.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [plex](https://plex.tv/)  to make simple media center that all people without technical knowledge can use and stream over the net or local network

> https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200288666-Opening-Plex-Web-App

Also, this is good to see [kodi](http://kodi.tv).

For multicasting or another media server you should see:

[wowza](https://www.wowza.com/products/streaming-engine/) - a media server for Flash, Silverlight, Apple iOS (iPhone/iPad), QuickTime, 3GPP mobile, IPTV and game console video/audio streaming.

[icecast](http://www.icecast.org/) -  a GPL streaming media server

[helix](http://www.realnetworks.com/products-services/helix) - delivers MPEG-DASH, RTSP, HTTP Live Streaming (HLS), RTMP.

[Red 5 server](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server) - Apache-licensed media server for RTMP and HLS

Also, it's may be helpful:

> http://blog.eltrovemo.com/364/diy-broadcast-how-to-build-your-own-tv-channel-with-open-source-other-goodies/`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately Plex doesn't support live multicast streaming. Plex is only on-demand streaming and that's not what we're looking for.

Comment: I improved my answer as my best. I hope it's be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLC remote control. It has different interfaces: HTTP, RC. You can find more information here https://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html

Or you can write simple program to control VLC. Here is link to C# program: 
https://github.com/UnickSoft/VLCControl